# Ruby on Rails: Overwrite instance variable on Selenium tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, selenium, testing, rspec

I have an action in my controller that loads up an instance variable with an instance of an object from an API I have no control over:

```
def index
  @obj = MyObj.find(id: params[:id])
end
```

MyObj.find makes an API call and returns me what that API returns.

Now say I want to write a test for my view, but I can't use a test database since my app is dependant on that API. I can never count on the API returning me a testable object and some of the tests I want to try are dependant on the state of that object.

I would like to be able to, before rendering my view, create my own test `@obj` manually and have my tests work on a view render informed by that `@obj`.

Ideally it would be something like this:

```
before(:all) do
  @obj = {attr1: "abc", attr2: 123}
  driver.navigate.to("#{ENV['RAILS_HOST']}/my_view/123")
end
```

Which clearly doesn't work. Is there some way to do this?

EDIT: Trying to stub the method doesn't seem to work, here's how it currently looks:

Spec:

```
before(:each) do
  allow(Library::Equipment)
    .to receive(:mymethod)
    .with(123)
    .and_return("Stub method")

  puts Library::Equipment.mymethod(123)
  #prints "Stub method"
  driver.navigate.to("#{ENV['RAILS_HOST']}/library/equipments/123/variables")
end
```

`/library/equipments/:equipment_id/variables` routes to `library/variables#index`, which looks like this:

```
def index
  @test = Library::Equipment.mymethod(123)
  puts @test
  #prints "Real method"
  # other code...
end
```

My `Library::Equipment` class has this class method:

```
def self.mymethod(param)
  "Real method"
end
```

And within my `index.html.erb` I simply have `<%= @test %>` to see what it contains. As you can see, the return of `mymethod` differs when called from my spec file and from my `index` action

Comment: Using `RSpec::Mocks.with_temporary_scope` will allow you to use stubbing in a `before(all)` but the stubbing will be removed when the scope ends. Please remove the `with_temporary_scope` AND change `before(:all)` to `before(:each)`/`before` at the same time.

Comment: The results are the same, I have edited the question to reflect the changes made.

Answer (score 1):

You can stub the call to `MyObj.find` via [rspec's allow](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs) method:

```
let(:obj) { { attr1: "abc", attr2: 123 } }
let(:obj_id) { 123 }

before(:each) do
  allow(MyObj)
    .to receive(:find)
    .with(id: obj_id)
    .and_return(obj)

  driver.navigate.to("#{ENV['RAILS_HOST']}/my_view/123")
end
```

`allow` will offer you the possibility to mock the response to a method call (e.g `find`) and return an answer of your choosing. That way, when your controller makes a call to `MyObj.find`, the actual implementation of `find` is not called, but rather rspec code which returns the object specified via `and_return`. The `with` method is only there to narrow down the mock so that the mock will not respond if the parameter doesn't match. It is probably optional in your case.

Please note that I altered the `before(:all)` to a `before(:each)`. The former would execute only once, before the entire suite. As you want independent tests, you don't want one altering `obj` which would spill over to the next test. Also, it seems not to be possible to access `let` in a `before(:all)` block

Given that Selenium tests are typically acceptance tests, I would find such a mocking suspicious, however.

If you don't have access to an external API, providing [canned responses](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) might be irritating to work with but at least the layer that is stubbed is clear.

Comment: I can't get that to work. I'm getting errors regarding "let declaration `obj_id` accessed in a `before(:context)` hook". Also, how exactly does that "allow" method work? Does it mean that any time I call MyObj.find(id: 123) it will return that specific object? This works within my controller?

Comment: @bpromas I elaborated the response to answer your questions.

Comment: This doesn't work. The `find` that runs within my controller's action (due to my `driver.navigate.to` call) runs normally and fails to find something with id = 123. However, if I call `MyObj.find(id: 123)` right under the `allow` method, it returns me `{ attr1: "abc", attr2: 123 }`, the way it should. Two questions: 1) MyObj here is meant to be a class, correct? 2) In my case, MyObj doesn't have a `find` method, but includes one from a support model. Does this change things?

Comment: Yes it does change things. When mocking/stubbing you'll have to identify the place in the code where you want to make the cut between executed code and stubbed one. So you would have to adapt the mock definition (`allow`) to your actual code, this applies to the object the method is called on as well as the method itself and the parameters. And that is why using mocking has a smell to it when using it with Selenium: 1) no blackbox texting 2) rather brittle.

Comment: Yeah, it's not working. If I make up a new method that I know belongs to `MyObj`, the method I build in `allow` isn't the one that's called in my controller, only if I call it within my spec file can I get the return that I want from it. :/

Comment: So what are you calling in your controller and what are you stubbing? Any chance to look into the code?

Comment: Certainly! I have added to my original question adding some real code I am using.